# add a delete file back into a branch with same name in git

Tags: git, github

I have a_file in branch_a got deleted.

Now I have branch_b with the same named a_file.

branch_b merge from other branch_c

so a_file is updated and merge

Now when I try to merge from branch_a <= branch_b automatically in github

It is complaining.

It gives me this suggestion:

Step 1: From your project repository, bring in the changes and test.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b ETL_R5 origin/ETL_R5
git merge ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL
```

Step 2: Merge the changes and update on GitHub.

```
git checkout ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL
git merge --no-ff ETL_R5
git push origin ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL
```

So I did:

```
git checkout -b etl_r5_blk_rtn_dtl origin/etl_r5
git merge ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL

CONFLICT (modify/delete): run_scripts/sql/BLK_RTN_DTL.sql deleted in HEAD and modified in ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL. Version ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL of run_scripts/sql/BLK_RTN_DTL.sql left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

How can I resolve this ?
I take a git course long ago it seems it is doing with the commit number.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The instructions are in the last line: `fix conflicts and then commit the result.` Git can't resolve the merge automatically for you, because it doesn't know what the result should be. You need to edit the files in your working tree so that they look like what you want the merge result to be, and then do `git commit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict is because `run_scripts/sql/BLK_RTN_DTL.sql` file is modified in both branches (delete in one branch and updated in other). That's why `git` is confused to keep which version. Since you need to keep the deleted file you can accept the `ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL` branch version.

You should add the deleted file back by accepting `ETL_MASTER_BLK_RTN_DTL` branch file and commit it.

To add the file

```
git add run_scripts/sql/BLK_RTN_DTL.sql
```

Then you should continue the merge

```
git merge --continue
```

It will prompt you with merge summary and commit message. You can finish commit here.

Further reading https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line#removed-file-merge-conflicts